# Wordpress Multisite installation issue on staging website

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, multisite

I am trying to change my website into multisite on my staging server.
When I add **define('MULTISITE', true);** in wp-config.php on my local machine setup, it works fine. Then I go to the Network admin and able to setup multiple sites. I add further code in .htaccess and wp-config.php.

But when I add **define('MULTISITE', true);** in wp-config.php on my staging site and refresh the page it show me the database connection error. I checked the database and I saw that it is not creating the required tables like, **wp_blogs, wp_blogsmeta, wp_site, etc.**
I tried to setup by adding the missing tables manually, but still it is showing the same error.

[image]
[image]

I checked my database credentials, everything is fine.

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake done by me.
For those who don't know:

1. Firstly you need to define this in wp-config.php:
   **define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);**
2. Then disable all your plugins.
3. Then Go to the **Dashboard > Tools > Network Setup**
4. Then choose if you want to create subdomain or the sub-directory(for localhost you can just create sub-directory).
5. Enter the Network Title and Network Admin Email and click on Install button.
6. Then copy the codes of **wp-config.php** and **.htaccess** and paste to the respective files.

   and it's done.